# Error while trying to solve ODE using Scipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, runtime-error, ode

I'm trying to solve a few differential equations using the SciPy library. Thus far I have an example of one which you can see below. The code works fine, but the execution time is quite long, and there is also an error in case nsteps < 10^6.

The error is:

```
0.1 [55.4662258]
0.2 [61.50134206]
0.30000000000000004 [68.16443669]
0.4 [75.52104176]
0.5 [83.64306141]
0.6 [92.61029686]
0.7 [102.51090657]
0.7999999999999999 [113.44178205]
0.8999999999999999 [125.51003611]
0.9999999999999999 [138.83414699]
1.0999999999999999 [153.54491757]
1.2 [169.78658954]
1.3 [187.71843357]
1.4000000000000001 [207.51637757]
1.5000000000000002 [229.37467955]
1.6000000000000003 [253.507774]
1.7000000000000004 [280.15236668]
1.8000000000000005 [309.56989072]
1.9000000000000006 [342.04876583]
2.0000000000000004 [377.90754689]
2.1000000000000005 [417.49804931]
2.2000000000000006 [273.12387997]
2.3000000000000007 [165.68845619]
2.400000000000001 [100.59106997]
2.500000000000001 [61.14730695]
2.600000000000001 [37.24734963]
2.700000000000001 [22.76575439]
2.800000000000001 [13.99098983]
2.9000000000000012 [8.6741386]
3.0000000000000013 [5.45252409]
3.1000000000000014 [3.50046623]
3.2000000000000015 [2.31766504]
3.3000000000000016 [1.60097602]
3.4000000000000017 [1.16671624]
3.5000000000000018 [1.00000093]

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ode.py", line 1009
    self.messages.get(istate, unexpected_istate_msg)))
UserWarning: vode: Excess work done on this call. (Perhaps wrong MF.)
3.600000000000002 [0.99999893]
```

If I increase nsteps to 10^6 or more, it works fine, but it takes even longer for the program to finish its work.

What could be done to speed up the execution of the program and to prevent such errors from occurring? For example what could be done that the max steps don't have to be set higher than 10^3?

Maybe by somehow decreasing accuracy? The results can be accurate only to 1 or 2 decimal places.

```py
from scipy.integrate import ode

r = 1.3
K = 1000000000
Gamma = 0.5
A_m = 6
phi_PS = 0.25
theta_PS = 0.01
delta_PS = 1
beta_BS = 0.1
N_BS = 25
L = 25


def F1(time, N_PS, par):
  if N_PS >= 1.0:
      return ((r * N_PS * (1 - (N_PS) / K) - theta_PS * N_PS - phi_PS * N_PS - par[0] * delta_PS * A_m * N_PS - Gamma * N_PS * 0.1) + beta_BS * N_BS)
  elif par[1] >= 1.0:
      return beta_BS * N_BS
  else:
      return 0


t0 = 0
y0 = 50
solver = ode(F1)
solver.set_integrator('vode', nsteps=10**5, method='bdf')
solver.set_initial_value(y0, t0)

dt = 0.1
while solver.successful() and solver.t < 20:
    time = solver.t
    next_t = time + dt
    x = 1 if (time >= 2 and time <= 4) else 0
    par = (x, L)
    solver.set_f_params(par)
    next_y = solver.integrate(next_t)
    if next_y < 1:
        L = L - 1
    print(next_t, next_y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a discontinuity when `N_PS=1`.  This will cause severe integrator issues.  If this is truly the function that needs to be integrated, I recommend to use three separate functions, i.e.

```
def F1(time, N_PS, par):
    return ((r * N_PS * (1 - (N_PS) / K) - theta_PS * N_PS - phi_PS * N_PS - par[0] * delta_PS * A_m * N_PS - Gamma * N_PS * 0.1) + beta_BS * N_BS)

def F2(time, N_PS, par):
    return beta_BS * N_BS

def F3(time, N_PS, par):
    return 0
```

Then you can use the `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` function with `events` to detect when to switch between the different regimes.  This should not suffer the same discontinuity problems that you see here.